# Reference an example in Stack Overflow Documentation in another example

Tags: feature-request, status-bydesign, documentation

I am reading documentation to learn about a software tool and have been improving the examples if I see an issue with them. In many examples I think that it would be very convenient if users could jump to a referenced example that is on the same or different documentation topic using a link click feature. Is this a feature that is already implemented and if so how do I use it? If it is not a I think it would be a great addition!

So for clarification: Someone is reading Example A that talks about Example B. I want to add a link to Example B that would cause the page to jump up or down to Example B.

Comment: you mean, like, an anchor tag? yeah... that's possible...

Comment: haha @KevinB I just don't know about it. Thats why i'm askin!

Comment: Look at the android getting started example for an... example. :)

Comment: Uh... just ... edit Example A to add a link to Example B? I'm not sure what I'm missing here. You can get the link from the "share" menu item below the example.